# how to get text from b tag inside a span class bs4

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
my code till now

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests,time

url = "https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.8615&lon=-87.0611"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.content,'lxml')

data2 = soup.find('span',{"class":"smallTxt"})
print(data2)
```

the output is **BRIDESHEAD REVISITED** by Evelyn Waugh

Comment: You want to get the coordinates ```Lat: 37.74°N Lon: 87.17°W, Elev: 407ft.```or just the text ```Lat: Lon: Elev:```? Because that's all that's inside the ```b``` tags

Comment: Note that I'm not getting the output ```<li class="alt"><strong>BRIDESHEAD REVISITED</strong> by Evelyn Waugh</li>``` nor do I see anything like it in the webpage, Rather I get ```<span class="smallTxt"><b>Lat: </b>37.74°N<b>Lon: </b>87.17°W<b>Elev: </b>407ft.</span>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code i cant get *BRIDESHEAD REVISITED*

You can try doing something like this, it's not robust, but it might work.

I define a dictionary and for each key I get its value.

To simplify the resolution I remove the colon from each key.

The format does not allow to iterate and take each key-value in the same row, so I define the key and its value (empty) and in the next round I insert it

```
result = {}
for i,v in enumerate(data2):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        key = v.get_text().split(':')[0]
        result[key] = ''
    else:
        result[key] = v
```

output:

```
{'Lat': '37.74°N', 'Lon': '87.17°W', 'Elev': '407ft.'}
```

Comment: i got it thanks for the comment